# Doxygen Unnamed Bitfields

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, doxygen

Currently i am working on structs with unnamed bitfields in Eclipse CDT C/C++ and Arm Cross GCC.

My struct is looking like:

```
/** @brief Struct to document */
struct mystruct {
    /** @brief Member to document */
    U32 FlagA : 1;
    U32 : 31;
};
```

Compilation works just fine.

But, doxygen does insert `__pad*__` members for the unnamed bitfields into the documentation.

**Please see:**

[image: Doxygen Output]

I am rather unhappy, that i could not find a way to remove the `__pad*__` members.

**My question is:**

How to get rid of these `__pad*__` members in doxygen?

Comment: The output does not match the declaration of your struct. Is this on purpose or is it just an example?

Comment: @Friedrich Just an example

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Keep in mind, however, that your question is more likely to get better answers if you posted your actual code.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Probably best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker at GitHub (I still see the same "problem" in with the current doxygen version).

Comment: Despite the missing issue on GitHub I've just created a proposed pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9905

Comment: Code of the proposed patch has been integrated into the master version on GitHub.